# opengl panning with glulookat

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to pan the camera across a 3d object, either left or right or up and down.  Up and down is easy enough ( just increment/decrment the y value).  Left and right is easy when x is 0 OR when z is 0.  However in the case when neither x or z is 0, simply incrmeenting/decrementing by a constant does not work.  Is there a mathematical formula for this?

Comment: By increasing/decreasing x/y/z values for the location of camera, you are not actually panning the camera, just moving it. I would suggest you to look up the meaning of panning and learn how to use gluLookAt() function as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

It really doesn't matter what value has your x OR z, gluLookAt() is just defining your starting point of view with current parameters.

I suggest you read some documentation about [panning](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/opengl/article.php/c2683/Panning-zooming-and-rotation-in-OpenGL.htm). It's very nice documentation, only after understanding the principle, you will do it with closed eyes :)

You can read more about LookAt function here:
1.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368663(v=vs.85).aspx
2.http://www.felixgers.de/teaching/jogl/gluLookAt.html

Comment: Hi Mikael, i am also looking for panning functionality in android.[i need to move the GLSurfaceview using touch event]. if you have any idea now ,I saw some tutorial about pan.but, i cant get clear idea. pls give any sample code. it would be helpful for me to complete my task.i am struggle here.see my sample code here http://www.mediafire.com/download/55lp59gdq78a3q3/LineDraw_Test.zip